# SQL: exclude certain criteria from select

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Trying to exclude a set of values that meet the criteria from the query, but the query returns nothing.

```
select *
from rpt_StockInventorySummary a
where a.[DepartmentId] ='P'
and not exists (
select *
from rpt_StockInventorySummary b
where b.Manufacturer = 'warrington'
and b.LowestGroupDescription = 'Boots, Leather, 14 Inch, Pro'
and b.Instock = 0
and b.barcode = a.barcode
)
order by a.SortOrder
```

**Edit**

I think adding "and b.barcode = a.barcode" at the end of the query in the NOT EXISTS was what was missing.

Comment: Without sample data and expected results, difficult to say. If it's returning no results, however, that means that the `NOT EXISTS` is return rows, or there are no rows where `DepartmentId` has a value of `'P'`.

Comment: Do you need your second and not exists? Can you not add an `AND` clause to the first select with the extra filter criteria. Your second select doesn't correlate back to your first one so it's not used.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the `NOT EXISTS` first, as I suspect if you run that query on it's own, you'll get a result set. It also seems odd that the `EXISTS` makes no reference to `rpt_StockInventorySummary` aliased as `a`.

Comment: The query inside the NOT EXISTS does return values, with or without the departmentId = 'p.' i just need the values from this query to be excluded, but i'm not sure why it's causing the no return...

Comment: If the `NOT EXISTS` query returns no rows, then you have no rows in the table `rpt_StockInventorySummary` where `DepartmentId` has a value of `'P'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was missing from the query was this:

```
and b.barcode = a.barcode
```

Adding this to the query inside of the not exists did the trick.